# Slot machine like control in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am writing a program for WP7 in C# where I would like to utilize a slot machine like effect where the numbers roll like they are mounted on a drum. Is there an efficient implementation of such a control? Any suggestions to implement such a control?

Comment: Would the [looping selector](http://www.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/31/windows-phone-looping-selector-for-digits.aspx) be of any use to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something similar to the iPhone date picker, but for any set of numbers.  A group called [Bee Mobile released such a DatePicker](http://beemobile4.net/products/metropolis/controls/datepicker) in a control pack they are selling, which suggests that it can be done efficiently.  You might find [Nick Randolph's adaptation](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/16/Windows-Phone7-Wheel-Control-e28093-Updated.aspx)* of the wheel effect to the standard ListBox to be helpful.  Depending on your requirements, you may be able to just alter the style to make that work for you.  If not, a [similar question at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsphone7series/thread/f27bdae7-cbf0-4a5b-b736-70521a728ea5) has a helpful outline of a possible approach among the replies:

- build the basic elements
- reuse and animate TextBoxes
- add styling for 3D appearance

*The original post referred to on Nick Randolph's blog is [here](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/10/Windows-Phone-7-Wheel-Control.aspx).  It has a bit more explanation, and a screenshot.